# How To Populate XMLGregorianCalendar()

Tags: java, binding, jaxb

I need to populate a JAX Bean from XML, however there is no setter method.  I get the following message below

```
 Failed to invoke public javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar() with no args
```

I wrote the following methods to take a date and transform it to XMLGregorianCalendar, and then call a setter in my wrapper class.  However I still get the exception.  Is there a standard way of handling this data type that I am overlooking?  Maybe my wrapper class is not calling it, but Netbeans won't allow me to attach a debugger to it for some reason.

```
public XMLGregorianCalendar asXMLGregorianCalendar(java.util.Date date) throws DatatypeConfigurationException {
    DatatypeFactory datatypeFactory = DatatypeFactory.newInstance();
    if (date == null) {
        return null;
    } else {
        GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar();
        gc.setTimeInMillis(date.getTime());
        return datatypeFactory.newXMLGregorianCalendar(gc);
    }
}
```

The setter in the Bean is below

```
public void setDeliveryDate(XMLGregorianCalendar value) {
    this.deliveryDate = value;
}
```

Comment: are you trying to populate it from XML as the question said, or are you trying to populate it from a Date object as your sample code shows?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your sample code shows you trying to populate it with a Date object, while the question itself says you are trying to populate from XML.  So unless I misunderstand, to populate from XML just use:

```
XmlGregorianCalendar cal = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(yourXmlDateTimeString);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using Joda Time -- The Java Date Api frustrates a lot of developers. If you want to stick with the core libraries, try using a DataTypeFactory.

```
public static XMLGregorianCalendar asXMLGregorianCalendar(Date date) {
    java.util.GregorianCalendar calDate = new java.util.GregorianCalendar();        
    calDate.setTime(date);
    javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar calendar = null;
        try {
            javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory factory = javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory.newInstance();
            calendar = factory.newXMLGregorianCalendar(
            calDate.get(java.util.GregorianCalendar.YEAR),
            calDate.get(java.util.GregorianCalendar.MONTH) + 1,
            calDate.get(java.util.GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH),
            calDate.get(java.util.GregorianCalendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),
            calDate.get(java.util.GregorianCalendar.MINUTE),
            calDate.get(java.util.GregorianCalendar.SECOND),
            calDate.get(java.util.GregorianCalendar.MILLISECOND), 0);
        } catch (DatatypeConfigurationException dce) {
            //handle or throw
        }   
    return calendar;
}
```